# Modify and rebuild Openfire plugin

Tags: java, openfire

I am trying to modify the message monitoring plugin in [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

I checked-out the code using svn. And i could also figure out what and where i will need to change the code. But I am not clear about rebuilding the plugin and testing my changes.

In Eclipse, I can export the "plugins.monitoring" package as a `.jar`, but it does not export all the classes. For example, it exports `plugins.monitoring.src.web` but ignores classes in sub-packages (if i am not wrong with the term) such as `plugins.monitoring.src.java.org.jivesoftware.openfire.reporting.util`.

How do I compile only one package and export it to `.jar` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got how to do this. It is to be done using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

build.xml can be found in the build directory inside the Openfire source code

Comment: ok. But what do you do if you rebuild the whole openfire source code after modifying the file say offlinemessages.java? Do I have to take the openfire.jar and replace it with the openfire.jar after the build?